# Object#to_s vs __id__ aka object_id

Tags: ruby, objectid

I probably should take a course on using google, but I just can’t find out an answer.

When one calls `to_s` on the instance of class, that does not have an ancestor, overriding `to_s`, `Object#to_s` is being called and the output looks like:

```
"#<TestClass:0x136e3544>"
```

According to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-to_s):

> The default `to_s` prints the object’s class and **an encoding of the object id**.

What the heck means “encoded” here? It’s not an `id` itself:

```
▶ t = TestClass.new.to_s
#⇒ "#<TestClass:0x137e6b94>"
▶ t.__id__
#⇒ 163526070
▶ "0x%08x" % t.__id__
#⇒ "0x09bf35b6"
```

According to ruby source, it is a heap memory address:

```
str = rb_sprintf("#<%"PRIsVALUE":%p>", cname, (void*)obj);
```

Now the question is: is there any relation between `__id__` and what’s being printed in default `to_s` at all?

**NB** Credits to @MarekLipka: possibly this behavior may be reproduced under VirtualBox only. It sounds like on native env the following does the trick:

```
"0x%08x" % (t.__id__ << 1)
```

Comment: It wasn't easy, but I found the answer to your question on SO.

Comment: Thanks, @MarekLipka, but unfortunately the answer given there is either obsolete, or just not correct. For the class above: `"0x%08x" % (t.__id__ << 1) #⇒ "0x137e6b6c"`. The difference in last two digits is significant for me, since I want to keep compatibility with what ruby does.

Comment: It's strange since I even tested it on my machine, 2.1.5 version and it was correct:
`t = TestClass.new`

`# =>  #<TestClass:0x00000002b798a8>`

`'%x' % (t.object_id << 1)`

`# => "2b798a8"`

Comment: @MarekLipka Uhm. Please note, that `to_s` returned `0x137e6b94` (last two digits.)

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: @MarekLipka both `2.1.1`, `2.2.0`.

Comment: I tested it on 2.2.0 moment ago, same (correct) result. Strange. But I'm reopening the question, maybe someone has an idea why this happens in your environment.

Comment: @MarekLipka I would blame VirtualBox I was testing under. On clean env everything is as expected. I updated the answer, please mark it back as a duplicate.

Comment: I can't do it second time. :)